# Wrapping an asynchronous generator in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, generator

Since Python 3.6 and [PEP 525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/) one can use [asynchronous generator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-asynchronous-generator):

```py
import asyncio

async def asyncgen():
    yield 1
    yield 2

async def main():
    async for i in asyncgen():
        print(i)

asyncio.run(main())
```

I created a function which is able to wrap any asynchronous generator, the same way you would wrap a basic function using `@decorator`.

```py
def asyncgen_wrapper(generator):

    async def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        print("The wrapped asynchronous generator is iterated")

        gen = generator(*args, **kwargs)

        try:
            value = await gen.__anext__()
        except StopAsyncIteration:
            return

        while True:
            to_send = yield value

            try:
                value = await gen.asend(to_send)
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                return

    return wrapped
```

Wrapping an asynchronous generator seems quite complicated compared to wrapping a basic generator:

```py
def gen_wrapper(generator):
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
        return (yield from generator(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapped
```

I mainly concerned about **correctness** of my wrapper. I want the wrapper to be as transparent as possible regarding the wrapped generator. Which leads me to have two questions:

- Is there a more straightforward way to implement a decorator for asynchronous generators?
- Does my implementation handle all possible edge cases (think to `asend()` for example)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Correct" is nebulous. If it were to mean here something like "the semantics of any wrapped generator through the public API is the same as if it were not wrapped, apart from a print statement before the generator is created", then, no, the code isn't correct since it doesn't preserve the effects of raising an exception or closing the generator. For example,

```
import asyncio

class StopItNow( Exception ): 
    pass

async def f():
    try:
        yield 0
    except StopItNow:
        yield 1

async def g( f ): 
    x = f()
    print( await x.asend( None ) )
    print( await x.athrow( StopItNow ) )

asyncio.run( g( f ) )
asyncio.run( g( asyncgen_wrapper( f ) ) )
```

. I think it would be a non-trivial undertaking to "correctly" implement a wrapper. Interestingly, in the same PEP (525) that you've linked in your question,

> While it is theoretically possible to implement yield from support for asynchronous generators, it would require a serious redesign of the generators implementation.

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/#asynchronous-yield-from

. You might find that it's a whole lot easier to implement some sort of injection or parameterise the generator itself to accept callables.

Otherwise, from my experimentation and taking hints from [PEP 380](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/#formal-semantics), there are implementation details that are omitted from PEP 525 that would be necessary to emulate the behaviour of an unwrapped generator.

This is the result of some toying around:

```
import functools
import sys

def updated_asyncgen_wrapper( generator ): 

    @functools.wraps( generator )
    async def wrapped( *args, **kwargs ): 
        print( "iterating wrapped generator" )

        gen = generator( *args, **kwargs )
        to_send, is_exc = ( None, ), False

        while True:
            try:
                do = gen.athrow if is_exc else gen.asend
                value = await do( *to_send )
            except StopAsyncIteration:
                return
            try:
                to_send, is_exc = ( (yield value), ), False
            except GeneratorExit:
                await gen.aclose()
                raise
            except:
                to_send, is_exc = sys.exc_info(), True

    return wrapped
```

. This isn't "correct" either, since it doesn't disambiguate between an attempt to close the generator and an explicit throw of an instance of `GeneratorExit`, which is, though, marked distinctly for usage by the [former case](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#GeneratorExit). This *might* be *good enough* for internal use.